# StoreKit Alert "Thank You. Your purchase was successful. [OK]" presentation logic

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit

We include iOS In-App purchases in several apps (multiple targets, different brands of the same codebase);

During our testing, we found that sometime at the end of the purchase process the alert "Thank You. Your purchase was successful. [OK]" is shown, while some times it's not.

We've tested on several devices, several apps, several sandbox users, and we could not find a reproduction path: same app tested at once on two identical devices (model, OS version), with brand new sandbox users, the alert is showing on one app and not on the other one.

To make it clear, the purchase process is always successful, the transaction is closed, and everything is working properly; Only the alert is sometime missing.

What's the exact logic behind that?